# JPA save() not updating existing rows

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

**What's the problem?**

We use the **static ids for primary keys**, We don't want auto-increment value as a primary key.

We use static id's to save the data into database. First time it's working I’m fine, all data inserted into database.
Now we are trying to update the data with existing **id**, got the following error

```
could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [tbl_lookup.PRIMARY]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

**Full Error Log:**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lookUpConfig': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [tbl_lookup.PRIMARY]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:160) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at com.example.basics.SpringBasicsApplication.main(SpringBasicsApplication.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [tbl_lookup.PRIMARY]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:276) ~[spring-orm-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233) ~[spring-orm-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:566) ~[spring-orm-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743) ~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711) ~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654) ~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407) ~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy125.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.basics.lookup.LookUpConfig.save(LookUpConfig.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.basics.lookup.LookUpConfig.lambda$insertLookUps$0(LookUpConfig.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.forEach(Arrays.java:4204) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.basics.lookup.LookUpConfig.insertLookUps(LookUpConfig.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:157) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:46) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3375) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3908) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:344) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1407) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:489) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3290) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2425) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:449) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562) ~[spring-orm-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '220000001' for key 'tbl_lookup.PRIMARY'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:117) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1098) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1046) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1371) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1031) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    ... 69 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

My JPA code:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "MyApp", name = "TBL_lookup")
public class JpaLookup implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(unique = true,insertable = false,updatable = false, nullable = false)
private Integer id;

 //other columns here
}
```

Sample data:

```
  id      name   
--------------------------
  100     CityName  
  101     CountryName
```

My jpa save code:

```
private void save(Lookup<? extends Enum> T, Integer groupLookupId) {
    System.out.println("status: " + T.generateJpaLookup(groupLookupId).getNameEn());
    Optional<JpaLookup> lookupOptional = lookUpRepository.findById(T.getLookupId());
    if (lookupOptional.isPresent()) {
        System.out.println("enum values: "+ T.toString());
        System.out.println("jpa values: "+ lookupOptional.get().toString());
        //some business logic
        //And update here
        lookUpRepository.save(T.generateJpaLookup(groupLookupId));

    } else{
        lookUpRepository.save(T.generateJpaLookup(groupLookupId));
    }
}
```

Comment: if possible, add some relevant codes where and how you are saving

Comment: Please show the code where you are doing the update and please add the **full stacktrace** instead of a partial snippet.

Comment: What's the purpose of your `@Column` annotation ? `@Id` does already the job.

Comment: @M.Deinum  I add the full stacktrace and update code

Comment: @grigouille I'm newbie to spring development. It's by mistake

Comment: Is that the real code? YOu are regenerating everything each time, and you are also using optionally in a wrong way. The stacktrace also points to an error during startup, it appears to insert the same data again.

Comment: @M.Deinum It's test project. I convert the static enums to jpa.  user404 answer fixed my issue. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems this is not correct inside your ***if (lookupOptional.isPresent()) {...***
statement.

```
lookUpRepository.save(T.generateJpaLookup(groupLookupId));
```

You need to save the existing object already stored on your database which is currently being fetched by the id. Try like this:

```
JpaLookup entity= lookupOptional.get();
entity.setNameEn("dsfdsf"); //not sure if name is present or not, just update anything
lookUpRepository.save(entity);
```

Comment: Yes, its working fine!  Why it's not working with my previous code? If you share me the reason it will helpful for me.

Comment: `You need to save the existing object already stored on your database which is currently being fetched by the id. Try like this:`  This is the reason.

Answer (score -1):

Problem seems like you have set updatable as false, which we generally do when we are using composite key.

try using `updatable = true`

Comment: same error, even I tried now,  updatable = true